# multiple backgrounds android adt

Tags: background, slideshow

Using ADT Android IDE to develop an android app. I would like to create a background that changes the image every 4 seconds to a new image. I have about 30 images I want to use. I can set the background for 1 image but I don't know how to make it change automatically.

Can anyone help me? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting closer. I added this code but I don't understand the second part.

> ```
>   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>" <transition  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>   <!-- The drawables used here can be solid colors, gradients, shapes, images, etc. -->
>  <item android:drawable="@drawable/original_state" />
>  <item android:drawable="@drawable/new_state" /> </transition>
> ```

Where does this go?

TransitionDrawable transition = (TransitionDrawable) viewObj.getBackground();
transition.startTransition(transitionTime);